# Pyspark SaveAsTable not infering schema from SQL

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a table from the output of a SQL query by doing the following:

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(self.sc)
j = "select a as a1, b as b1, c as c1 from x"
df = self.sqlContext.sql(j)
df.write.saveAsTable(target_table)
```

This saves the table with 2 columns - key and value instead of the columns a1, b1, c1. I guess this is happening because i am not defining the schema here. But the same approach used to work with the deprecated df.saveAsTable(table) where it used to infer the schema automatically.

Have things changed with the new DataFrameWriter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify format when using `saveAsTable`.

However, there is another approach to save DataFrame to Hive table.

1. Create a temp view.

   `df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")`
2. Run Spark sql to create table from this temp view.

   `spark.sql("create table if not exists tbName as select * from df")`